# How can I high pass (DSP) filter a low frequency signal without introducing lag?

Tags: filter, software, dsp, matlab

I need to high pass filter a signal, and my design just isn't cutting it.  The part that's making it tricky is that I can't tolerate lag.  I am sampling at 20Hz, the signal I care about is 1/12 to 1/4Hz, and my system has to be as real time as possible (a lag of 2 seconds for signal processing is about all I can handle).  The corner frequency is flexible, but has to be below 1/10Hz worst case.

I have been using an IIR-like lowpass filter like this:

```
signal_low_freq(n) = (signal_low_freq(n-1)*(filter_constant - 1) + (sensor_data(n))) /filter_constant;

signal_ac(n) = sensor_data(n) - signal_low_freq(n);
```

where filter_constant = 165.

It has low latency, but also introduces a large amount of phase related error (I measured it at about 100 samples of lag).

I have used Matlab's fdatool, and can get great results with a high order FIR filter, but that's obviously far too much lag.

Does anybody have a good solution to this DSP problem?

As a note: in the audio range, it's analogous to sampling at 48kHz and high-pass filtering with a corner frequency somewhere between 150Hz and 240Hz.

Comment: Is that the exact code? -- 'cause you're missing an index for sensor data in the first line.  Can you pop up a figure for the step response of your filter, and signal_low_freq?

Comment: Good catch on the missing index, I fixed it.  It's practically line by line the code, with all the names changed so nobody gets upset.  The filter I outlined is garbage and doesn't work well at all, but DSP isn't my strongest skill set and I don't know what else to do that won't introduce major lag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you're up against a fundamental limitation of real, causal physical systems. You're asking for a filter that can distinguish between signals that have periods of 12 to 16 seconds, but only allowing it to "look at" a 2-second segment (1/6 to 1/8 of the period) of the waveform in question. It simply isn't possible to get no phase shift *and* low delay under these circumstances.

Can you provide some more context for this problem? What is the nature of the signals, and why is such low processing latency required?

Comment: I thought I might be hitting a wall; I was hoping someone with more experience could bend the rules and steer me to a solution. The problem is inertial, relating to accelerometer data, and trying to get position when in sinusoidal motion in real time.  If the position isn't almost real time it becomes useless. I know you need to filter out low freq error (dc and bias drift) right up front,and I havent seen anything but Kalman filters as a solution.  The IIR-ish filter I describe takes care of some of the low freq, but has awful phase characteristics, introducing a pile of low freq. error.

Comment: Ah. In that case, you're taking an approach that's too simplistic. The DC and low-frequency components you want to reject are much lower frequency than your inertial signal, so you use a very low cutoff freqeuncy filter (a couple of orders of magnitude below your signal frequency) to separate them. This filter can be a simple recursive filter, or a sophisticated Kalman filter and yes, it can take a long time to initialize. But then, when you subtract its output from the raw signal, the navigation signal is left over with virtually no effect on its phase/delay characteristics.

Comment: When I was looking at phase characteristics of, e.g., IIR filters in Matlab's fdatool, it had horrible phase characteristics at my signal frequencies, even if I pushed the corner frequency well below my signal.  Is there a specific type of IIR or other recursive filter that I'm missing that wouldn't effect my signal's phase as much?